# How to get a create view from viewmodel with list of objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

How to get a create view from viewmodel with list of objects

I have a list of objects and what I want to do is to have multiple "create" views in one view for the objects.

```
public class TaskItemsViewModel
{
    List<TaskItem> myTaskItems = new List<TaskItem>();
}
```

So in the controller I will create several temporary objects for the list and then in the view you can edit those. I want to create something like you would have with a store where you can just say "add another item" and it just goes into the view but when saved to the database you have as many as were in the view.

When I do the automatic create view in Visual studio I do not get an iterator (for each in model) at all.

How can I get the functionality I want, to be able to get multiple creates in a view?

Sorry if I am not asking the question correctly I am new to asp.net mvc and not sure how exactly to do what I want to do here.

Comment: check out this article http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/12/22/editing-a-variable-length-list-of-items-in-aspnet-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Steven Sanderson blogged about how to [edit a variable length list](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).